# Set up PostGIS on the postresql database

Tags: openstreetmap

as I Prepare the POSTGRES database, I found the problem as below, please help me find the problem. thank you

psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6653: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6659: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6665: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6703: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6752: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6775: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6781: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6805: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6816: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6821: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6826: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6944: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
psql:/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis.sql:6949: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you try to install PostGIS to a database without PLPGSQL enabled.
Issue the command `createlang plpgsql yourdatabase` and try again.